# Protect branch in Github results in "Rule is invalid"

Tags: github, branch

I'm trying to create a simple rule to protect the `main` branch of a repository but it results in `Rule is invalid`. I am the creator of the repo. Using GitHub Enterprise Server 2.22.6.

What am I missing?

**Steps:**

1. Settings
2. Branches
3. New Rule
4. <strike>Name the rule</strike> Enter branch name to protect (answer)
5. Select `Require pull request review before merging`

[image]

6. Create

**Error:** Rule is invalid

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `Branch name pattern` dialog box is meant to contain the name of a branch or a regular expression to capture multiple branch names. It is not meant to contain the name or description of a branch protection rule.

Try entering a regular expression or the name of the branch you'd like to protect (e.g. `main` instead of `Protect Master`) into the `Branch name pattern` textbox.

See [the docs here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-a-branch-protection-rule) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I was seeing the input box (step 4 above) as "Give this rule a name" instead of "Select branch to protect".

Comment: Same here :-D They should give this box a different name or add an example that explains what is expected to be filled in here

Answer (score 8):

For anyone still struggling with this. Make sure there is no space in your rule name.

**ie:**

"Protect Main" -> error

"ProtectMain" -> fine.

Answer (score 0):

Name the rule as the branch name, so that it is applied to the specific branch you intend.